# Combining multiple getElementById statements into one

Tags: javascript

I have a number of statement on a page that apply a click listener to a specific element identified with an ID.  What would be the most efficient way to combine these into one statement?

```
document.getElementById("foo1").addEventListener("click", function(){doSomething('bar1')});
document.getElementById("foo2").addEventListener("click", function(){doSomething('bar2')});
document.getElementById("foo3").addEventListener("click", function(){doSomething('bar3')});
```

Comment: The most efficient (and only recommendable way IMO) would be [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate). Add a single click handler on the document, add your elements selectors in a pull you'd test event.target against, and map your callback from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper that takes the id and the callback for the event listener and do something like this:

```
function addListenerToId(elemId, cb) {
    document.getElementById(elemId).addEventListener("click", cb);
}
```

And then:

```
addListenerToId('foo1', cb1);
addListenerToId('foo2', cb2);
addListenerToId('foo3', cb3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the "foo" and "bar" are the same and all that changes is the number, we could just put it in a for loop!

```
for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){
document.getElementById("foo"+i).addEventListener("click", function()
{doSomething('bar'+i)});
}
```

If you can't just do it with I as a number, you could make it a string first using the .toString() method. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Make a for loop that iterates from 1 to the max number and when you use the id just add i to `foo` or `bar`:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    document.getElementById("foo" + i).addEventListener("click", function(){doSomething('bar' + id)});
}
```

Also if you only need to select all elements with id starting with `foo` for example you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='foo']").forEach((e) => {  
  e.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-attributes` to store the text and bind the click event to every element.

This is an example using `a` elements.

```js
function doSomething(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.dataset.text);
};

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((e) => {  
  e.addEventListener('click', doSomething);
});
```

```html
<a href="#" id="foo1" data-text="bar1">Foo1</a>
<a href="#" id="foo2" data-text="bar2">Foo2</a>
<a href="#" id="foo3" data-text="bar3">Foo3</a>
```